# How to change background color of table row if quantity column has numeric value less than or equal to 10

Tags: php, html, css

I am implementing cloth shopping website in which stock is added to the database by admin and admin can view, update and delete stock as well. while displaying record in table from the database I want that the item from stock that has quantity becomes 10 or less than 10 after customer purchasing that row color becomes red so that it should be alert for the admin that particular stock quantity is low.
Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Sr.No</th>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Image</th>
    </tr> 
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM add_stock ORDER BY id DESC"; 
    $rs_result = mysqli_query ($query);
    while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result) )
    {
    ?>
        <?php $qty =$result['dress_quantity']; ?>
          <tr <?php if($qty<=10){echo 'style="background:red"';} ?> >
            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['brand_name'];</td>
            <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['gender_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['category_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['material_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['size_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $result['image'] ?>','mypopuptitle', '_parent')" >View Image</a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

CSS CODE:

```
table {  
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    border-collapse: 
    collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th {  
    border: 1px solid; /* No more visible border */
    height: 30px; 

    transition: all 0.3s;  /* Simple transition for hover effect */
}

th {  
    background: #DFDFDF;  /* Darken header a bit */
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}

td {  
    background: #FAFAFA;

     height: 40px;
}

/* Cells in even rows (2,4,6...) are one color */        
tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #F1F1F1; }   

/* Cells in odd rows (1,3,5...) are another (excludes header cells)  */        
tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #FEFEFE; }
```

Comment: Your query is missing a closing quote. Is that just a typo in your question here, or is that in your actual code?

Comment: typo in question not actual code i edit it

Comment: Isn't the `tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #FEFEFE; }` on top of the `style="background:red"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class in CSS like .isLess

```
.isLess { background-color:red;}
```

Then do something like this:

a ternary operator echoing the class, if qty is < 10, add the class, if not don't output anything.

```
<tr <?php echo ($result['dress_quantity'] < 10 ? "class='isLess'" : ""); ?> >
            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['brand_name'];</td>
            <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['gender_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['category_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['material_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['size_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $result['image'] ?>','mypopuptitle', '_parent')" >View Image</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
$class = "";
if($result['dress_quantity'] < 10) { $class='isLess'; }
<tr <?php echo $class; ?> >
```

Comment: @ShoaibSharoon please accept as the answer so others can see :)